# Array in request payload

Tags: javascript, php, request, httprequest

I am sending some image data to backened server. The problem is that, for the same code the request payload is different at our different server.

So i am making an request like this :

```
 sign_type.push("string");
```

And adding this to fields like this :

```
 fields.sign_type = sign_type;
 fields.image_data = imageDataArray;
```

And making call like this :

```
     Upload.upload({
                    url: 'api/test',
                    method: 'POST',
                   file: files,
               imageData: imageDataArray,
                  fileName: filesName,
                  fields: fields,
                 fileFormDataName: 'file'
        }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
//                     
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

       });
```

But the problem is that for this same code i get different request payload at different server :

**Server 1 (Working fine)**

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryIWviAIcICxBA9gts
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sign_type[0]"
>
> string
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryIWviAIcICxBA9gts
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sign_type[1]"
>
> string
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryIWviAIcICxBA9gts
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_data[0]"

**Sever 2( not working) :**

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryWb0UyBYCZAa6YGAG
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sign_type"
>
> ["string","string"]
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryWb0UyBYCZAa6YGAG
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_data"

Comment: Actually found issue, it was related to upload directive version, which i was using to call the API with some file upload